# Find out the Complexity of algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

Find out the complexity of an algorithm that measures the number of the print statements in an algorithm that considers a positive integer n and prints 1 one time, 2 two times, 3 three times, and n for n times.
That is 
1
2 2
3 3 3
……………
……………
n n n n ……..n  (n times)

Comment: I answered what I thought to be your question - if possible, please clarify your question so those looking for the same answer can find the same answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the problem is to find the algorithmic complexity of an algorithm, which when given a number *n* will print every number from 1 to *n*, printing 1 once, 2 twice, 3 thrice, and so on...

Your algorithmic complexity has an upper bound of O(*n*²).

This is because for *n* there are *n* prints. Realistically, if you want the tilde approximation, it should be ~O( (*n*² + *n*) /2) because you average out the sequence.

For *n* = 5, you print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 times... which is 15.

For *n* = 6, you print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 times... which is 21.

For *n* = 10, you print 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 times... which is 55 times.

Since the actual algorithmic complexity is indeed O( (*n*² + n) / 2), your largest order of magnitude of complexity is *n*². You are better off approximating your algorithmic complexity as O(*n*²) because your *n*² will quickly outgrow your *n* with a large enough input size.